# C# Web API Controller, Context Based Progess Reporting

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I have an app which uploads an xml to the server via ajax and  does some processing liking parsing,schema validation,connecting to the db based on the conn string present in the xml data.These validations,connection and data extraction is being done in the same function of the controller. I want to update my viewer the steps that has already been completed. Since I cannot return the function ,so I created a file in which the the given function will write the update and another ajax call via different function of the same controller will read the file and display it on the page.This is working fine except that if i connect to the app from two browsers the information get overlapped. What other alternative can you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using dotnet 4.5? Would it be possible for you to use SignalR, at various points your controllers action to send back progress messages to the browser?

You should also consider using Async methods

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using .net 4.5. I'll look into signalR . For the async method can you please explain in detail or a provide reading source.

Comment: Sure, the official asp.net article on it covers the majority of it. http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4.  Essentially, using an Async method is preferable to a blocking Sync method when doing large amounts of computation as it is non-blocking.

Comment: I forgot to mention, if you used SignalR, you could report back the progress of one-connected client, to all other connected clients.  You have to have Javascript enabled for this though.